# program segment prefix address 00h-001h content type?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, dos, x86-16

In the wikipedia page about PSP says that the content in address 00h-001h is "CP/M exit (always contains INT 20h)", i want to know: Is it a string or an hex value ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you can see on the Wikipedia page it's two bytes long. So it's a binary value - the hex code for `INT 20h`.

Comment: so it would be something like this: 49 4e 54 20 32 30 68 ???

Comment: No. I meant the _assembled_ hex code of `INT 20h`. The answer is correct.

Comment: @SamuR no, that would be string... it's `int 20h` in machine code, i.e. "operation code" which the CPU does recognize (it does not recognize string  "int 20h", that has to be handled by assembler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously that's a hex value. How is a seven character string `"INT 20h"` going to fit in two bytes? The INT 20h instruction fits just fine in two bytes, though:

```
CD 20
```